# TypeScript - error TS1146: Declaration expected

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I got the latest [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) via npm (`npm install -g typescript`)

`Version 1.7.5`

When I run the typescript compile command on my file: `tsc app.component.ts --module system`

I get the following error: `app.component.ts(15,7): error TS1146: Declaration expected.`

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

    @Component({
        selector: 'my-app',
        // template: '<h1>My title: {{title}}</h1> <h2>Hardcoded h2</h2>'
    })
    @View({ // <- line 7
        templateUrl: '/templates/home.html',
        directives: []
    })
    .Class({
        constructor: function() {

        }
    }); // <- line 15

export class AppComponent {
    title = "My First Angular 2 App";
}
```

Anyone know what this error means?

Comment: i may be wrong, but don't you need to import `View`? line 1: `import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';`

Comment: You are right actually, I also found another answer saying I need to remove the `;` at the end of my component. Now getting a different error `error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'.` lol want to post your answer? This is what I updated the top line with `import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/core';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to import `View` from `angular2/core` as well:

`import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';`

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: when downvoting please state why..
This answer is not valid because he is not using rc to begin with, he is still using beta or alpha, as you can see from import statement : 'angular2/core', which now has moved to the @angular namespace in rc.

`import { Component, View } from '@angular/core';` would be correct in newer versions.